Como puedo conectar una bbdd remota de Turso App en Python?
Tengo un programa llamado SnakeGame y este cuenta con datos como puntos, record y record máximo y esos datos yo los guardo en una bbdd en local con la librería sqlite3, pero tambien lo quiero guardar en una remota con Turso App.
Este es mi código:
# Codigo que guarda el record en remoto y local

import sqlite3 as sqlite
import libsql_experimental as libsql

# Record del juego guardado en bbdd local

class RecordLocal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bbdd = sqlite.connect("SnakeGame.db")
        self.cursor = self.bbdd.cursor()
        self.datos = []

    def guardar_record(self, record):

        if record > self.datos[0][-1]:
            self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO SnakeGame(Records) VALUES({record});")

    def mostrar_record(self):
        self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT MAX(Records) FROM SnakeGame;")
        self.datos = self.cursor.fetchall()

        return self.datos[0][0]

    def guardar_cambios(self):
        self.bbdd.commit()

    def cerrar_bbdd(self):
        self.bbdd.close()

# Record del juego guardado en bbdd remota

class RecordRemoto(RecordLocal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = "****"
        self.url = os.getenv("libsql://snakegame-bredalis2013.turso.io")
        self.procesar_token = os.getenv(self.token)

    def conectar_bbdd(self):

        self.bbdd = libsql.connect("snakegame.db", sync_url = self.url, 
            auth_token = self.procesar_token)
        self.bbdd.sync()

# Juego completo
# Librerias

import pygame
import random
from Record import *

# Instancia para acceder 
# al record del juego 

guardar_record = RecordLocal()
guardar_record_remoto = RecordRemoto()

# Inicir pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

# Tamaño de la ventana

ANCHO, ALTO = 550, 500

# Colores

VERDE = (0, 255, 0)
BLANCO = (255, 255, 255)

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))
pygame.display.set_caption("SnakeGame")

# Crear imagen de la manzana

manzana_img = pygame.image.load("Apple.png")
manzana_rect = manzana_img.get_rect()
manzana_rect.center = (ANCHO // 2, ALTO // 2) # Posicion

# Crear serpiente

serpiente_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 30, 20)
velocidad_x = 5
velocidad_y = 0

puntos = 0
record = 0

run = True
reloj = pygame.time.Clock()

# Logica del juego

while run:

    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        elif evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pygame.mixer.music.load("Spinning.mp3")
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                if velocidad_x == 0:  
                    velocidad_x = -5
                    velocidad_y = 0

            elif evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pygame.mixer.music.load("Spinning.mp3")
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                if velocidad_x == 0:
                    velocidad_x = 5
                    velocidad_y = 0

            elif evento.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pygame.mixer.music.load("Spinning.mp3")
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                if velocidad_y == 0:  
                    velocidad_x = 0
                    velocidad_y = -5

            elif evento.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pygame.mixer.music.load("Spinning.mp3")
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                if velocidad_y == 0:
                    velocidad_x = 0
                    velocidad_y = 5

    # Velocidad de la serpiente

    reloj.tick(40)

    # Mover la serpiente en cada iteración

    serpiente_rect.x += velocidad_x
    serpiente_rect.y += velocidad_y

    # Dibujar los personajes

    ventana.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ventana.blit(manzana_img, manzana_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(ventana, VERDE, serpiente_rect)

    # Mostrar puntos

    fuente = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)
    texto_puntos = fuente.render(f"Puntos:  {puntos}", True, BLANCO)
    texto_record = fuente.render(f"Record:  {record}", True, BLANCO)
    texto_record_maximo = fuente.render(f"Maximo Record:  {guardar_record.mostrar_record()}", True, BLANCO)

    ventana.blit(texto_puntos, (30, 30))
    ventana.blit(texto_record, (130, 30))
    ventana.blit(texto_record_maximo, (230, 30))

    if serpiente_rect.colliderect(manzana_rect):
        pygame.mixer.music.load("Eating.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

        nueva_posicion_x = random.randint(0, ANCHO - manzana_rect.width)
        nueva_posicion_y = random.randint(0, ALTO - manzana_rect.height)
        manzana_rect.topleft = (nueva_posicion_x, nueva_posicion_y)

        puntos += 1
        record = max(record, puntos)

        guardar_record.guardar_record(record)
        guardar_record_remoto.guardar_record(record)

    # Ajustar las dimensiones de la serpiente para que se doble

    if velocidad_x != 0:
        serpiente_rect.width = 30 + puntos * 10
        serpiente_rect.height = 20 

    elif velocidad_y != 0:
        serpiente_rect.width = 20
        serpiente_rect.height = 30 + puntos * 10

    # Fin del juego

    if (serpiente_rect.left < 0 or serpiente_rect.right > ANCHO or
            serpiente_rect.top < 0 or serpiente_rect.bottom > ALTO):

        pygame.mixer.music.load("GameOver.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        run = False

        if run != True:
            puntos = 0
            serpiente_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 30, 20)
            run = True

    pygame.display.flip()

# Guardar cambios y cerrar bddd

guardar_record.guardar_cambios()
guardar_record.cerrar_bbdd()

pygame.quit()


El problema que tengo es que la libreria dice que no esta instalada y ya lo hice. Alguien ha trabajado con con Turso App en Python?
Ya estuve buscando algunas posibles soluciones, pero dicen que instale la librería, podrian saber el por que dice que no se encontro el modulo si lo instale?

Sugiero que publiques el mensaje de error exacto, si tiene una traza, también. Y verifica también si no es que instalaste en un entorno y estás ejecutando en otro.

Okey, voy a revisar, gracias
